# Camel xslt component to create static sql query from given xml data

Tags: xslt, apache-camel

I want to create a sql query from xml data using camel xslt component. I have tried to create html page using xsl file (created from xml file) using xslt component. But there is not enough information about generating sql query from camel xslt component.

The one which I tried is as below:

**xml data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="employee-sql.xsl" type="text/xsl" ?>
<Employees>
    <employee>
    <empName>Abc</empName>
    <empAddress>Delhi</empAddress>
   </employee>
</Employees>
```

**employee-sql.xsl file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/" name="TemplateA">
  <xsl:param name="param">
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:value-of select="/Employees/employee" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
<body>
<xsl:output method="xml" />

<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="/Employees/employee" mode="normalize-space" /></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="text()" mode="normalize-space"><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)" /></xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="normalize-space"><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="normalize-space" /></xsl:copy></xsl:template>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The xsl file I have generated here is taken from internet source. Could anyone please tell me how do I create xsl file for generating sql query(like select * from {xml data} from xml data

Comment: If you are open to alternatives to xslt, you could unmarshal the xml to a pojo of type Employee and then feed the pojo to a processor to create an sql query.

Comment: What do you want as an output? You don't show what should be generated.

Comment: I want to generate sql query from given xml data (like select * from <xml data>) using Camel xslt component and then save that query to some file.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is to:

1. switch output from XML to text

> `<xsl:output method="text"/>`

2. use xpath concat function to generate the SQL statements:

> ```
> <xsl:variable name="table_name" select="mytable">
> <xsl:value-of select="concat('SELECT * FROM ', $table_name)" />
> ```

Comment: I tried with below changes

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0">
 <xsl:template match="/" name="TemplateA">
  <xsl:param name="param">
  </xsl:param>
  <xsl:value-of select="/catalog/book" />
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <html>
   <body>
<xsl:output method="text" />

<xsl:variable name="table_name" select="mytable">
<xsl:value-of select="concat('SELECT * FROM ', $table_name)" />

<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="/catalog/book" mode="normalize-space" /></xsl:template>
   </body>
  </html>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>